# How is this device getting low voltage?

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, ac-dc

I've opened up a Lutron dinner, and I'm trying to understand how the microprocessor gets its DC voltage. With my limited knowledge I'm not seeing an AC/DC converter. I've attached pictures, can someone explain how this works?

[image: front]
[image: back]

Comment: What's a Lutron dinner? How does it taste?

Comment: *I'm not seeing an AC/DC converter* You'd need at least one diode, I see at least two.

Comment: Also I doubt it's a dimmer, I see no TRIAC or such. Looks like a switch to me. With a PIR movement detector. And don't **assume** there's a microcontroller there. For a PIR switch it's not needed, a few opamps or a dedicated chip can do the job. It seems to have a simple resistive voltage dropper, the 3 light blue resistors, elco on one side, Z2 to limit the voltage. Not rocket science ;-)

Comment: @FakeMoustache. Normally these have a reactive power supply using a Mylar capacitor of about .68uF. The rest looks much like you mentioned , but maybe using a relay instead of a triac. The two buttons indicate this dimmer has user controls as well.

Comment: @fakemoustache - you're right! It's not a dimmer, it's a PIR motion switch. There is a microprocessor, a TI 430AFE251 on the front, above the PIR. So, to help me further: you can see my knowledge is limited, and I do see the resistors, but I don't understand how this is being converted to DC for use by the microprocessor?

Comment: @Sparky256 there is a relay: Axicom V23079-E1201. But that would just switch the power for the attached load, not convert AC into DC, no?

Comment: @beeudoublez. Correct. It takes the place of a triac, or it is the main power switch for the board. Too many details missing.

Comment: That device is probably sold as an "occupancy sensor", intended to  be used in some sort of smart lighting system.

Comment: Althoug you accepted AndyW's answer I think he's wrong about how the low voltage is made. I am quite sure that Bruce's answer is actually the correct one. So reverse engineer the schematic and see who is right.

Comment: @FakeMoustache I *kinda* see what you're saying, but I'm not seeing the delta between the two approaches. Both answers say that the diodes are providing rectification, and use a zener diode as a shunt regulator. What am I missing here? I'll trace the circuit and post here a little bit later, tricky as the parts are tiny.

Comment: There is a big difference, the difference is that AndyW says there's a **chopper transistor (Q8?)** and I think there isn't. Controlling such a transistor would require a more complex circuit and possibly an IC. Also D3 and D4 are very close to the relay's coil, they're **not** near the high voltage input which is at the bottom near the green wire. Note how the blue resistors are at some distance to the other parts, that's how a proper **high voltage** circuit must be made. I do not see such component distance near D3 and D4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is undoubtedly an "AC/DC" convertor on the board, since the TI micro needs 3.3V DC nominally to operate. However, you're probably expecting to see an inductor or two, and a switching power supply control IC, which there isn't. That's because the circuitry consumes so little power, it's not necessary to go this route. Instead, I think the AC is directly rectified (D3, D4), and then probably "chopped" by a series pass transistor (Q8?) operating at a fixed duty frequency/duty cycle directly into the large electrolytic filter cap, with a paralleled zener diode for regulation (Z2?).

Of course, this is merely a guess, since we don't have anything approaching a circuit schematic to reference.

Comment: This was a very helpful answer, thanks! I was expecting to see a switching power supply, but you've explained that the circuitry doesn't consume much power, that makes sense. The two diodes D3 and D4 are SM56 models, which shows them to be rated w/breakdown voltage of 61.6. I suspect that's because there is one for each leg (120v coverage). [0] Now I know where to head, I'll keep reading on chopped rectification and break out the oscilloscope. Any other thoughts to leave me with? [0] http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/275277/MIC/SM56.html

Comment: Be very careful with the scope. unless the scope inputs are the floating input type, connecting the ground probe to places in this circuit will short circuit power to ground. Remember neutral and ground are connected together. see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xaELqAo4kkQ

Answer (score 3):

The AC/DC convertor is a rather crude circuit with dropper resistors, rectifier diodes and a Zener shunt regulator. After this there should be a regulator IC which supplies the MCU with a more stable voltage.

Due to the high voltage drop it will only be capable of supplying a very low average current, but the large filter capacitor may hold enough charge to pulse a latching relay on and off.

Your images are too fuzzy to trace reliably, however I think the circuit may look something like this:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7Wrun.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that the 'ground' symbol in this diagram is just to satisfy the simulator. In reality the entire circuit should be considered live!

Comment: My guess is also that this is what is used instead of what AndyW says in his answer.